# How do you use an if statement to check if a function returns "true"?

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, boolean

Here is my function

```
bool straightFlush(int card1, int card2, int card3, char color1, char color2, char color3){

        if(card1+1 == card2 && card1 + card1+2 == card3 && color1 == color2 && color1 == color3)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is how I currently am trying to check if my function, "straightFlush" returns "true"

```
         if(straightFlush == true)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
```

Comment: If the function requires six parameters, you're going to have to call it with six parameters.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you might think about wrapping a card value/suit pair in a class/struct as well as the concept of a hand which is a collection of cards.  If not, it'll be quite tiresome if you decide to handle a game with 7 card hands.

Answer (score 1):

You must invoke it, but since you are already returning a `bool` there's no need to check for equality with `true`, eg:

```
if (straightFlush(x,y,z,a,b,c)) {
  ..
}
```